# How do I exit nvim? (neovim)

Tags: neovim

When it first opened, it said:

```
~                type  :help nvim<Enter>       if you are new! 
~                type  :checkhealth<Enter>     to optimize Nvim
~                type  :q<Enter>               to exit         
~                type  :help<Enter>            for help
```

But when I type `:q` <kbd>Enter</kbd> it just appears in the body?

How do you stop `nvim` without running `pkill nvim`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vim / Neovim has different modes, the most common are :

- **Normal mode** : you can't insert text, but you can use commands such as `:q` for quit
- **Insert mode** : you can type/modify text => use **i key** to enter in Insert mode
- **Visual mode** : mode to select text

When you type `:q` if you see it typed into the document you're already in Insert mode => press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to return in Normal mode then quit Vim/Neovim with `:q` command.

You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> `:q` to quit if you were already in insert mode.

Answer (score 0):

Press Escape. You probably activated insert mode.